# How to connect laravel with firebase php package?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I'm new here and new to firebase .
I want to implement the firebase into my laravel project. 
So I used `kreait/firebase-php` package for it . But I don't know how  to use it . 
I have firebase controller page and firebase.json file.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use \Kreait\Firebase\Database;
class FirebaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/Firebase.json');
        $firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount);
        ->create();
        $database = $firebase->getDatabase();

        $newPost = $database
        ->getReference('users')
        ->push([
        'title' => 'Testing data to add' ,
        'category' => 'from Laravel'
        ]);
        echo "<h3> Data inserted</h3>";
    }

}
```

But I'm getting this error .

> Kreait\Firebase\Factory::create is deprecated. Use the component-specific create*() methods instead.

Why?

Comment: Others have already answered to the specific problem, but I'd like to add that there's a dedicated Laravel package for the SDK at https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase - if you receive deprecation warnings like the one you experienced here, you will probably find hints in the changelog, here: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#4340---2019-10-13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `createDatabase` method instead of `create` method which is deprecated in `v4.33` . 
Change your controller file as follows :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use \Kreait\Firebase\Database;
class FirebaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/Firebase.json');
        $firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount);

        $database = $firebase->createDatabase();

        $newPost = $database
        ->getReference('users')
        ->push([
        'title' => 'Testing data to add' ,
        'category' => 'from Laravel'
        ]);
        echo "<h3> Data inserted</h3>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Kreait\Firebase` class has been deprecated. Please instantiate the services you need directly:

```
# recommended
$factory = (new Firebase\Factory())
// ->withServiceAccount(...)
// ->...
// no call to ->create()
;

$auth = $factory->createAuth();
$database = $factory->createDatabase();
$messaging = $factory->createMessaging();
$remoteConfig = $factory->createRemoteConfig();
$storage = $factory->createStorage();
```